# how many Java Garbage Collector objects?

Tags: java, multithreading

Can anyone please tell me if we call garbage collector in parallel executing two threads, how many gc objects are created?

Answer (score 2):

There's always only one garbage collector, that runs in it own `Thread`

Comment: thanks antoine, yes Runtime is a singleton but when we are calling Runtime.gc(), jvm internally it will created one thread that is garbage colletor(daemon thread) . but in this case when we call gc in two different threads at a time, how many GC objects will be created .

Comment: @RajasekharBurepalli Calling `gc()` does NOT create a new thread. `gc()` simply runs the finalization methods of any objects pending finalization.

Comment: @John - Half right.  You are correct that it does not create a new thread.  But calling `gc()` does NOT *"simply runs the finalization methods of any objects pending finalization"*.  It actually runs the garbage collector, and typically it does a **full** GC.

Comment: thanks Stephen and @John. but we are saying that GC is daemon thread and also gc() has native implementaion.then what is GC?

Comment: @StephenC The garbage collector is always running/sleeping alongside the main thread, so I am not sure what you mean by `gc()` "runs" the garbage collector. Calling System.gc() does not even guarantee that a full garbage collection will occur. If it DOES occur, garbage is collected, and the finalize method is called for each object that is garbage (which is what I said before in less words).

Comment: @John - Actually, it is not what you said before. That's why I corrected you. (Reread your original comment, and my comment where I corrected you.  I could spell it out in excruciating detail ... but I don't think other readers would be interested.)

Comment: @John - And if you are confused by what I said in my comment, I've explained it in more detail in my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's one garbage collector as others pointed out.
You should not care about the count of the garbage collector objects
or about any details about the garbage collector. This is something
on JVM/system level. All you care about is when to call the garbage
collection explicitly (if you want to do that).

Answer (score 1):

(This is responding to the OP's comments which reveal the nature of the misunderstanding that is at the root of his Question.  See the quoted text ...)

> yes Runtime is a singleton but when we are calling Runtime.gc(), ...

Correct

> ... the jvm internally it will created one thread that is garbage colletor(daemon thread).

Incorrect.  It does not create a new GC thread.  Rather it causes the existing GC thread to wake up and do a garbage collection.  Furthermore:

- the thread that calls `gc()` will not return until the garbage collector has completed.
- depending on the garbage collector that has been configured, the garbage collector *may* freeze all other application threads before starting the collection.

> ... but in this case when we call gc in two different threads at a time, how many GC objects will be created?

None.  If two methods call `gc()` at the same time, the GC will run once on the existing GC thread.  Think of the GC as an "engine" that is either running or sleeping at any point in time.  Calling `gc()` will *typically* cause the GC to start running if it is currently sleeping.

(Actually, I'm simplifying things a bit.  CMS and G1 have the complication that the `gc()` will typically run in parallel with application threads.  Another possibility is that the `gc()` call will be simply ignored.  Finally, the GC typical has a variety of modes; e.g. a young generation collection, and a full collection.  Calling `gc()` will start a full collection.)

> ... but we are saying that GC is daemon thread

Yes (sort of),

The GC may have multiple threads.  There is typically a main GC thread, and another thread for handling finalization.  And for some kinds of GC, some tasks are performed in parallel using a pool of threads.

> and also gc() has native implementation

For mainstream JVMs, yes.  (But as a counter-example, in JNode is implemented in Java, albeit using `Unsafe` methods, etc.)

> then what is GC?

It is the "stuff" that does garbage collection.  What actually goes on under the hood is JVM specific, and depends on JVM options, etcetera.